# Sudden issue with Windows dual booting

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, boot

I have a Toshiba Laptop (Satellite C850-B516) for which I need dual booting. I have already Windows 7 and Windows 8 installed. The first few days both worked fine, but now when I choose Windows 8, a message shows up says:

> "Your PC ran into a problem and needs to restart. We're just collection some error info, and then we'll restart for you."

After restarting and choosing Windows 7, a black screen shows up and says:

> "checking file system on D:......
>     one of your disks needs to be checked for consistency. " etc

What's the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: @TheUser1024 - How is that a duplicate?  The user has both Windows 7 and Windows 8, the Windows 8 installation is corrupt, the linked question talks about upgrading Windows 7 to Windows 8.

Comment: @Ramhound: my thought was, because it describes how to set it up. but i get your point and have deleted my comment.

Comment: Try fixing boot from [Windows 7 Recovery Console](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/tutorials/windows-7-recovery-environment-command-prompt/) on Windows DVD

Comment: @bobSmith1432: when click the link, "Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to www.bleepingcomputer.com".

Comment: Bob's link work fine for me.

Comment: i tried again but it didn't open, is there any solution?